# Only By Giving in Latin

Tags: motto

How do I write *"Only by Giving"* in Latin, trying to nurture a *'Spirit of Giving'*, for example, *"Only by Giving can we fulfill the purpose of life."*

What would be the best option? Would it be,

**SOLUM PER DATIO**

I like Datio because of it's meaning of 'A gift', which makes our service seem like a gift we can choose to give to others our to a cause. I also find it sonorous, short and sweet, concise yet powerful.

Would **SOLUM DATIO** be a viable alternative also? Although more concise, I fear the sense of meaning would be lost, that it would be too generic a statement.

Does anyone else prefer another option? Like,

*TANTUM (AB) SUMMINSTRATIO / SUBMINSTRATIO*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Per Dationem***

***Datio,*** your suggestion looks like an ablative (by with or from) but is Nominative. 
But it is a good choice

> *dătĭo , ōnis,* f. *do,* 
>   I.the act of giving, allotting, distributing; giving up, surrender (good prose, but rare)

If you add ***per*** with the Accusative that would be an improvement

> Per II.C. To designate the reason, cause, inducement, etc., through, for, by, on account of, for the sake of:

for 'only,' perhaps use

> III.B. Sup.: pŏtissĭmē (pŏtissŭ- ), and more freq. pŏtissĭmum (pŏtissŭ- ), chiefly, principally, especially, in preference to all others, above all, most of all (class.). ([search under *'potis'* III. B](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=potis&highlight=) )

(all Dictionary quotations are from Lewis and Short through [Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059) )

Comment: Thanks, but you wouldn't include Solum?

Comment: *haud aliter* looked promissing at first, but has tricky requirements of verb and construction; does *pŏtissĭmē* (Edits) fit your meaning?

Comment: If, after all, you prefer *sōlus,* make it Accusative Feminine Singular to agree; *per dătionem sōlam.*

Comment: Wow, thanks. Why would I take the Feminine *Solam* rather then the Neuter *Solum*? eg. *Non Nobis Solum.*

Comment: *dătĭo , ōnis,* f. the "f." tells you that 'giving' is feminine. For the grammar it doesn't matter who gives; the 'giving' is feminine. [War, *bellum,* is neuter, A Casserole, *olla,* is feminine; *dătĭo* is feminine; it just is.]

Comment: Oh, sorry. That's not the question you were asking. Don't use ***solum*** as an adverb. It means "Hence, adv.: sōlum , alone, only, merely, barely" which seems completely the wrong meaning, doesn't it?

Comment: ...and ***solus*** meaning yourself could be taken to mean "alone, lonely, solitary, forsaken, deserted; without relatives, friends"

Comment: Is that why it's suitable in Non Nobis Solum but wouldn't be suitable here? Because of the *possible* negative connotation?

Comment: It was because of Non Nobus Solum that I wanted Solum, so that my new motto would 'recall' that great saying

Comment: I prefer Solam if it can be used but now dear the negative connotation I was previously unaware of. Non nobis solum nati summus, et solam per dationem (... Etc ...)

Answer (score 2):

How about a gerund, "dandum" = "giving"; "dando (ablative) explemus" = "we fulfil by giving". Here "us"/ "ourselves" is understood (the Romans used fewer words than we do; things being understood). But, if you wish personal, accusative pronoun "nos" (used reflexively) may be added.

Personal pronouns of first & second person, when used reflexively, can be strengthened (covering your request for "only") by applying an intensifier, a part of "ipse" = "self".

Giving: "dando (nos ipsos) explemus".

Alternatively, "solum" or "modo" = "just"/ "only", instead of the reflexive element.

Answer (score 2):

A gerund was my first thought in response to this. So 'Solum dando' would be nice and concise for a motto.

Comment: Welcome to the Community!

Comment: Thank you Adam. That's very kind.